# Two Post Install Exceptions occurred while installing Health Cloud

Tags: exception, postinstall, health-cloud

We are installing Health Cloud into a new, clean org. The pre-installation steps were carried out prior to the installation, ie Chatter enabled, Contact to multiple Accounts, etc.

After the installation happened I received two emails notifying me of Post Install Exceptions. I can't find anything useful online and don't know how serious these are in terms of the implementation.

I'd like to know what the resolution of these will be;

- can these be resolved manually?
- does anything need to be re-installed?
- can I continue building on Health Cloud until these are resolved?
- how will I know when the issues are resolved?

I don't want to continue building if Health Cloud needs to be uninstalled and re-installed.

The first exception message is around Knowledge:

> An exception has been thrown while running a job flow. Exception Data
> Exception Message:    Invalid field PermissionsAllowViewKnowledge for
> PermissionSet Line no:    127 Stack Trace
> String: Class.HealthCloudGA.HcPermissionSettingsPostInstallJobs.CreatePermSetSystemPermissions.addSystemPerms:
> line 127, column 1
> Class.HealthCloudGA.HcPermissionSettingsPostInstallJobs.CreatePermSetSystemPermissions.addSystemPermissions:
> line 42, column 1
> Class.HealthCloudGA.HcPermissionSettingsPostInstallJobs.CreatePermSetSystemPermissions.createSystemPermissions:
> line 22, column 1
> Class.HealthCloudGA.HcPermissionSettingsPostInstallJobs.CreatePermSetSystemPermissions.processJob:
> line 17, column 1
> Class.HealthCloudGA.HcJobFlowManager.queryJobsAndExecute: line 62,
> column 1 Class.HealthCloudGA.HcJobFlowManager.run: line 35, column 1
> Class.HealthCloudGA.HcPostInstallScript.onInstall: line 14, column 1
> Cause:    null

The second is around a duplicate value:

> An exception has been thrown while running a job flow. Exception
> Message:  Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found:
> HealthCloudGA__YearConditionCodeHCCCode__c duplicates value on record
> with id: a0U8d000003WfzY: [] Line no: 49 Stack Trace
> String:   Class.HealthCloudGA.HcEhrPostInstallJobs.LoadCondToHccCodesQueueable.execute:
> line 49, column 1 Cause:  null

If anyone can shed any light on either the cause of these, or how to resolve them without re-installing I'd be extremely grateful.

Andrew

Comment: Regarding the first exception, the Post-install script assumes that you have the Knowledge feature enabled, but looks like your organization does not. You should be able to still use Health Cloud.

Comment: Thanks Swetha, you're right, that's something we're working on once licences are approved. In terms of the exception, how do I resolve that once Knowledge is up and running. Is that just a permission that I need to create on user profiles? I'm still new to adding managed packages.